# Haskell for mission-critical systems

Tags: haskell, mission-critical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Haskell for sizable real-time systems: how (if?) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263711/using-haskell-for-sizable-real-time-systems-how-if)

Is it feasible to use Haskell in mission-critical software? (like avionics,space technology etc.)