# Haskell for Robotics

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, embedded, robotics

I am looking up on web about Haskell and its applications. Basically i trying to learn functional programming language and i see Haskell is very famous among them. What i want to know is, is it possible to use Haskel as substitute for c in robotics? Can i use Haskell for embedded system programming and getting data from sensors, moving the motors, implementing mathematical model that is used to design the robot and its behaviour and if possible apply machine learning algorithms?

I am just starting off in this field so if the question is naive enough, please answer like you would answer any newbie.

Update: If the Question is too broad, i would like to know the specifics. Do people compile down the haskell to the embedded hardware or use haskell as a remote control in most of the cases? Which one is more approachable using haskell? What is the general way of using haskell in hardware embedded programming? If it is only used as a remote control, how to implement genetic algorithms and machine learning algorithms using haskell? I know its too broad but i would just like to know the general usage if my requirement is such.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  Do you have any specifics?  Maybe how to convert some C code into Haskell (with your current attempt) or a question about how to get Haskell compiled for a specific embedded platform?

Comment: What about this question (first hit on google for `haskell embedded`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263711/using-haskell-for-sizable-real-time-systems-how-if

Comment: That question is pretty old. These days we have better examples, such as the smaccms project which uses a Haskell DSL to pilot a quad copter.

Comment: I just want to know, how people use haskell on robotics like on quadrocopter, do they compile down the haskell and run it on embedded or use computer as a remote control for robots or quadrocopter. Is it even possible to do such thing using haskell??

Comment: I'd be happy to provide an overview of how to use Haskell in robotics.

Comment: Please I'd be happy to learn

Comment: @Anthony can you please refer me any blog post or book or any link that could help me with haskell and robotics?

Comment: Late to the party, but using ROS might help a lot, and there's https://hackage.haskell.org/package/roshask