# Use cases for Clojure in projects

Tags: java, clojure, jvm-languages

Of course I'm not talking about using Clojure just because I can.

I'm curious about where/when to use Clojure and what is the value it brings to a project.

Suppose I'm doing Java web development, where I can use Clojure? any use cases are in your mind?

Thanks.

Comment: [Just about the same question has been asked this Monday.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496895/how-to-apply-clojure) (There's more further back -- just look around!) See also [the results of Chas Emerick's State of Clojure, Summer 2010 survey](http://cemerick.com/2010/06/07/results-from-the-state-of-clojure-summer-2010-survey/) for some insight into what people use Clojure for (should have remembered this link in connection with that last question...).

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this thread poped up when I finished writing the subject. Thanks for referring me.

Comment: Sure. Not sure if SO will notify you of this, so note also that I've edited the first comment above to include an external link which is likely to be useful to you in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a long time rubyist and I believe that I'm far more productive in a dynamic language that has good facilities for interactive development (i.e. a repl).

Clojure gives me this productivity benefit while offering much better performance than ruby, better concurrency features, and does not require crossing a bridge of any form to interact with java libraries. It can also be compiled into java classes so I can make libraries for java people without them needing to know or care that it's clojure and not java code they are running.